# How to set BottomSheetDialogFragment to fullScreen?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bottomsheetdialog

I'm trying to make my `BottomSheetDialogFragment` to be  fullscreen when it's opened, the issue is that in any case the `Dialog` is shown half of screen height.

I've tried to set the peekHeight as the following:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    dialog?.setOnShowListener { dialog ->
        val bottomSheetBehavior: BottomSheetBehavior<*> = (dialog as BottomSheetDialog).behavior
        bottomSheetBehavior.peekHeight = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.heightPixels
        bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
    }
}
```

But the `Dialog` is shown as same as without the peekHeight.

Then i've tried to add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"`

In my `BottomSheet` layout but still had the same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this

```
 fun setupRatio(context: Context, bottomSheetDialog: BottomSheetDialog, percetage: Int) {
    //id = com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet for Material Components
    //id = android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet for support librares
    val bottomSheet =
        bottomSheetDialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.design_bottom_sheet) as FrameLayout
    val behavior: BottomSheetBehavior<*> = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)
    val layoutParams = bottomSheet.layoutParams
    layoutParams.height = getBottomSheetDialogDefaultHeight(context, percetage)
    bottomSheet.layoutParams = layoutParams
    behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
}
```

call this into onStart in your dialog

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    setupRatio(requireContext(),dialog as BottomSheetDialog,100)
}

 private fun getBottomSheetDialogDefaultHeight(context: Context, percetage: Int): Int {
    return getWindowHeight(context) * percetage / 100
}

   private fun getWindowHeight(context: Context): Int {
    // Calculate window height for fullscreen use
    val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
    (context as Activity?)!!.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
    return displayMetrics.heightPixels
}
```

Comment: what is `getBottomSheetDialogDefaultHeight`?

Comment: I update the code please check it